# Zephyr Driver Usage Example

Tags: camera, esp32, zephyr-rtos

I'm just getting started with Zephyr Development and getting accustomed to the device tree model. In particulat the ov2620 camera on the esp32 board. Basic applications work fine so I guess the setup is ok. Now I'm trying to use drivers for applications.

There is a zephyr driver the ov2620.

How would I start a basic application to initialize the camera and reads its version number from a register? I've attached the driver.

TIA

```
`/ {
    aliases {
                sw0 = &load_switch;
                led0 = &test_led_0;
                //ov2640 = &ov2640_0;
    };
    
    leds {
        compatible = "gpio-leds";
        test_led_0: test_led_0 {
            gpios = <&gpio0 15 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
            //label = "Test LED 0";
        };

        cam_flash: cam_flash {
            gpios = <&gpio0 4 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
            //label = "Test LED 0";
        };
    };
    
    load_switch: load_switch {
        compatible = "power-switch";
        //label = "Switch 0";
        gpios = <&gpio0 2 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
    };
    
};

&pinctrl {
    i2c_cam: i2c_cam {
        pinmux = <I2C0_SDA_GPIO26>,
                 <I2C0_SCL_GPIO27>;
        bias-pull-up;
        drive-open-drain;
    };
};

&i2c0 {
    status = "okay";
    clock-frequency = <I2C_BITRATE_STANDARD>;
    sda-gpios = <&gpio0 26 (GPIO_PULL_UP | GPIO_OPEN_DRAIN)>;
    scl-gpios=  <&gpio0 27 (GPIO_PULL_UP | GPIO_OPEN_DRAIN)>;
    pinctrl-0 = <&i2c_cam>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    ov2640: ov2640@61 {
        compatible = "ovti,ov2640";
        status = "okay";
        reg = <0x60>; 
    };

};`
```

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2021 Antmicro <www.antmicro.com>
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */

#define DT_DRV_COMPAT ovti_ov2640
#include <zephyr/kernel.h>
#include <zephyr/device.h>

#include <zephyr/drivers/video.h>
#include <zephyr/drivers/i2c.h>
#include <zephyr/drivers/gpio.h>

#define LOG_LEVEL CONFIG_LOG_DEFAULT_LEVEL
#include <zephyr/logging/log.h>
LOG_MODULE_REGISTER(ov2640);


struct ov2640_reg {
    uint8_t addr;
    uint8_t value;
};

static const struct ov2640_reg default_regs[] = {
    { BANK_SEL, BANK_SEL_DSP },
    { 0x2c,     0xff },
    { 0x2e,     0xdf },
    { BANK_SEL, BANK_SEL_SENSOR },
    { 0x3c,     0x32 },
    { CLKRC,    0x80 }, /* Set PCLK divider */
    { COM2,     COM2_OUT_DRIVE_3x }, /* Output drive x2 */
    { REG04,    REG04_SET(REG04_HREF_EN)},
    { COM8,     COM8_SET(COM8_BNDF_EN | COM8_AGC_EN | COM8_AEC_EN) },
    { COM9,     COM9_AGC_SET(COM9_AGC_GAIN_8x)},
    { COM10,    0x00 }, /* Invert VSYNC */
    { 0x2c,     0x0c },
    { 0x33,     0x78 },
    { 0x3a,     0x33 },
    { 0x3b,     0xfb },
    { 0x3e,     0x00 },
    { 0x43,     0x11 },
    { 0x16,     0x10 },
    { 0x39,     0x02 },
    { 0x35,     0x88 },
    { 0x22,     0x0a },
    { 0x37,     0x40 },
    { 0x23,     0x00 },
    { ARCOM2,   0xa0 },
    { 0x06,     0x02 },
    { 0x06,     0x88 },
    { 0x07,     0xc0 },
    { 0x0d,     0xb7 },
    { 0x0e,     0x01 },
    { 0x4c,     0x00 },
    { 0x4a,     0x81 },
    { 0x21,     0x99 },
    { AEW,      0x40 },
    { AEB,      0x38 },
    /* AGC/AEC fast mode operating region */
    { VV,       VV_AGC_TH_SET(0x08, 0x02) },
    { COM19,    0x00 }, /* Zoom control 2 LSBs */
    { ZOOMS,    0x00 }, /* Zoom control 8 MSBs */
    { 0x5c,     0x00 },
    { 0x63,     0x00 },
    { FLL,      0x00 },
    { FLH,      0x00 },

    /* Set banding filter */
    { COM3,     COM3_BAND_SET(COM3_BAND_AUTO) },
    { REG5D,    0x55 },
    { REG5E,    0x7d },
    { REG5F,    0x7d },
    { REG60,    0x55 },
    { HISTO_LOW,   0x70 },
    { HISTO_HIGH,  0x80 },
    { 0x7c,     0x05 },
    { 0x20,     0x80 },
    { 0x28,     0x30 },
    { 0x6c,     0x00 },
    { 0x6d,     0x80 },
    { 0x6e,     0x00 },
    { 0x70,     0x02 },
    { 0x71,     0x94 },
    { 0x73,     0xc1 },
    { 0x3d,     0x34 },
    /* { COM7,   COM7_RES_UXGA | COM7_ZOOM_EN }, */
    { 0x5a,     0x57 },
    { BD50,     0xbb },
    { BD60,     0x9c },

    { BANK_SEL, BANK_SEL_DSP },
    { 0xe5,     0x7f },
    { MC_BIST,  MC_BIST_RESET | MC_BIST_BOOT_ROM_SEL },
    { 0x41,     0x24 },
    { RESET,    RESET_JPEG | RESET_DVP },
    { 0x76,     0xff },
    { 0x33,     0xa0 },
    { 0x42,     0x20 },
    { 0x43,     0x18 },
    { 0x4c,     0x00 },
    { CTRL3,    CTRL3_BPC_EN | CTRL3_WPC_EN | 0x10 },
    { 0x88,     0x3f },
    { 0xd7,     0x03 },
    { 0xd9,     0x10 },
    { R_DVP_SP, R_DVP_SP_AUTO_MODE | 0x2 },
    { 0xc8,     0x08 },
    { 0xc9,     0x80 },
    { BPADDR,   0x00 },
    { BPDATA,   0x00 },
    { BPADDR,   0x03 },
    { BPDATA,   0x48 },
    { BPDATA,   0x48 },
    { BPADDR,   0x08 },
    { BPDATA,   0x20 },
    { BPDATA,   0x10 },
    { BPDATA,   0x0e },
    { 0x90,     0x00 },
    { 0x91,     0x0e },
    { 0x91,     0x1a },
    { 0x91,     0x31 },
    { 0x91,     0x5a },
    { 0x91,     0x69 },
    { 0x91,     0x75 },
    { 0x91,     0x7e },
    { 0x91,     0x88 },
    { 0x91,     0x8f },
    { 0x91,     0x96 },
    { 0x91,     0xa3 },
    { 0x91,     0xaf },
    { 0x91,     0xc4 },
    { 0x91,     0xd7 },
    { 0x91,     0xe8 },
    { 0x91,     0x20 },
    { 0x92,     0x00 },
    { 0x93,     0x06 },
    { 0x93,     0xe3 },
    { 0x93,     0x03 },
    { 0x93,     0x03 },
    { 0x93,     0x00 },
    { 0x93,     0x02 },
    { 0x93,     0x00 },
    { 0x93,     0x00 },
    { 0x93,     0x00 },
    { 0x93,     0x00 },
    { 0x93,     0x00 },
    { 0x93,     0x00 },
    { 0x93,     0x00 },
    { 0x96,     0x00 },
    { 0x97,     0x08 },
    { 0x97,     0x19 },
    { 0x97,     0x02 },
    { 0x97,     0x0c },
    { 0x97,     0x24 },
    { 0x97,     0x30 },
    { 0x97,     0x28 },
    { 0x97,     0x26 },
    { 0x97,     0x02 },
    { 0x97,     0x98 },
    { 0x97,     0x80 },
    { 0x97,     0x00 },
    { 0x97,     0x00 },
    { 0xa4,     0x00 },
    { 0xa8,     0x00 },
    { 0xc5,     0x11 },
    { 0xc6,     0x51 },
    { 0xbf,     0x80 },
    { 0xc7,     0x10 },
    { 0xb6,     0x66 },
    { 0xb8,     0xA5 },
    { 0xb7,     0x64 },
    { 0xb9,     0x7C },
    { 0xb3,     0xaf },
    { 0xb4,     0x97 },
    { 0xb5,     0xFF },
    { 0xb0,     0xC5 },
    { 0xb1,     0x94 },
    { 0xb2,     0x0f },
    { 0xc4,     0x5c },
    { 0xa6,     0x00 },
    { 0xa7,     0x20 },
    { 0xa7,     0xd8 },
    { 0xa7,     0x1b },
    { 0xa7,     0x31 },
    { 0xa7,     0x00 },
    { 0xa7,     0x18 },
    { 0xa7,     0x20 },
    { 0xa7,     0xd8 },
    { 0xa7,     0x19 },
    { 0xa7,     0x31 },
    { 0xa7,     0x00 },
    { 0xa7,     0x18 },
    { 0xa7,     0x20 },
    { 0xa7,     0xd8 },
    { 0xa7,     0x19 },
    { 0xa7,     0x31 },
    { 0xa7,     0x00 },
    { 0xa7,     0x18 },
    { 0x7f,     0x00 },
    { 0xe5,     0x1f },
    { 0xe1,     0x77 },
    { 0xdd,     0x7f },
    { CTRL0,    CTRL0_YUV422 | CTRL0_YUV_EN | CTRL0_RGB_EN },
    { 0x00,     0x00 }
};

static const struct ov2640_reg uxga_regs[] = {
    { BANK_SEL, BANK_SEL_SENSOR },
    /* DSP input image resolution and window size control */
    { COM7,    COM7_RES_UXGA},
    { COM1,    0x0F }, /* UXGA=0x0F, SVGA=0x0A, CIF=0x06 */
    { REG32,   REG32_UXGA }, /* UXGA=0x36, SVGA/CIF=0x09 */

    { HSTART,  0x11 }, /* UXGA=0x11, SVGA/CIF=0x11 */
    { HSTOP,   0x75 }, /* UXGA=0x75, SVGA/CIF=0x43 */

    { VSTART,  0x01 }, /* UXGA=0x01, SVGA/CIF=0x00 */
    { VSTOP,   0x97 }, /* UXGA=0x97, SVGA/CIF=0x4b */
    { 0x3d,    0x34 }, /* UXGA=0x34, SVGA/CIF=0x38 */

    { 0x35,    0x88 },
    { 0x22,    0x0a },
    { 0x37,    0x40 },
    { 0x34,    0xa0 },
    { 0x06,    0x02 },
    { 0x0d,    0xb7 },
    { 0x0e,    0x01 },
    { 0x42,    0x83 },

    /*
     * Set DSP input image size and offset.
     * The sensor output image can be scaled with OUTW/OUTH
     */
    { BANK_SEL, BANK_SEL_DSP },
    { R_BYPASS, R_BYPASS_DSP_BYPAS },

    { RESET,   RESET_DVP },
    { HSIZE8,  (UXGA_HSIZE>>3)}, /* Image Horizontal Size HSIZE[10:3] */
    { VSIZE8,  (UXGA_VSIZE>>3)}, /* Image Vertical Size VSIZE[10:3] */

    /* {HSIZE[11], HSIZE[2:0], VSIZE[2:0]} */
    { SIZEL,   ((UXGA_HSIZE>>6)&0x40) | ((UXGA_HSIZE&0x7)<<3) | (UXGA_VSIZE&0x7)},

    { XOFFL,   0x00 }, /* OFFSET_X[7:0] */
    { YOFFL,   0x00 }, /* OFFSET_Y[7:0] */
    { HSIZE,   ((UXGA_HSIZE>>2)&0xFF) }, /* H_SIZE[7:0] real/4 */
    { VSIZE,   ((UXGA_VSIZE>>2)&0xFF) }, /* V_SIZE[7:0] real/4 */

    /* V_SIZE[8]/OFFSET_Y[10:8]/H_SIZE[8]/OFFSET_X[10:8] */
    { VHYX,    ((UXGA_VSIZE>>3)&0x80) | ((UXGA_HSIZE>>7)&0x08) },
    { TEST,    (UXGA_HSIZE>>4)&0x80}, /* H_SIZE[9] */

    { CTRL2,   CTRL2_DCW_EN | CTRL2_SDE_EN |
        CTRL2_UV_AVG_EN | CTRL2_CMX_EN | CTRL2_UV_ADJ_EN },

    /* H_DIVIDER/V_DIVIDER */
    { CTRLI,   CTRLI_LP_DP | 0x00},
    /* DVP prescaler */
    { R_DVP_SP, R_DVP_SP_AUTO_MODE | 0x04},

    { R_BYPASS, R_BYPASS_DSP_EN },
    { RESET,    0x00 },
    {0, 0},
};

#define NUM_BRIGHTNESS_LEVELS (5)
static const uint8_t brightness_regs[NUM_BRIGHTNESS_LEVELS + 1][5] = {
    { BPADDR, BPDATA, BPADDR, BPDATA, BPDATA },
    { 0x00, 0x04, 0x09, 0x00, 0x00 }, /* -2 */
    { 0x00, 0x04, 0x09, 0x10, 0x00 }, /* -1 */
    { 0x00, 0x04, 0x09, 0x20, 0x00 }, /*  0 */
    { 0x00, 0x04, 0x09, 0x30, 0x00 }, /* +1 */
    { 0x00, 0x04, 0x09, 0x40, 0x00 }, /* +2 */
};

#define NUM_CONTRAST_LEVELS (5)
static const uint8_t contrast_regs[NUM_CONTRAST_LEVELS + 1][7] = {
    { BPADDR, BPDATA, BPADDR, BPDATA, BPDATA, BPDATA, BPDATA },
    { 0x00, 0x04, 0x07, 0x20, 0x18, 0x34, 0x06 }, /* -2 */
    { 0x00, 0x04, 0x07, 0x20, 0x1c, 0x2a, 0x06 }, /* -1 */
    { 0x00, 0x04, 0x07, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x06 }, /*  0 */
    { 0x00, 0x04, 0x07, 0x20, 0x24, 0x16, 0x06 }, /* +1 */
    { 0x00, 0x04, 0x07, 0x20, 0x28, 0x0c, 0x06 }, /* +2 */
};

#define NUM_SATURATION_LEVELS (5)
static const uint8_t saturation_regs[NUM_SATURATION_LEVELS + 1][5] = {
    { BPADDR, BPDATA, BPADDR, BPDATA, BPDATA },
    { 0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x28, 0x28 }, /* -2 */
    { 0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x38, 0x38 }, /* -1 */
    { 0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x48, 0x48 }, /*  0 */
    { 0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x58, 0x58 }, /* +1 */
    { 0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x58, 0x58 }, /* +2 */
};

struct ov2640_config {
    struct i2c_dt_spec i2c;
#if DT_INST_NODE_HAS_PROP(0, reset_gpios)
    struct gpio_dt_spec reset_gpio;
#endif
};

struct ov2640_data {
    struct video_format fmt;
};

#define OV2640_VIDEO_FORMAT_CAP(width, height, format) \
    { \
        .pixelformat = (format), \
        .width_min = (width), \
        .width_max = (width), \
        .height_min = (height), \
        .height_max = (height), \
        .width_step = 0, \
        .height_step = 0 \
    }

static const struct video_format_cap fmts[] = {
    OV2640_VIDEO_FORMAT_CAP(160, 120, VIDEO_PIX_FMT_RGB565),   /* QQVGA */
    OV2640_VIDEO_FORMAT_CAP(176, 144, VIDEO_PIX_FMT_RGB565),   /* QCIF  */
    OV2640_VIDEO_FORMAT_CAP(240, 160, VIDEO_PIX_FMT_RGB565),   /* HQVGA */
    OV2640_VIDEO_FORMAT_CAP(320, 240, VIDEO_PIX_FMT_RGB565),   /* QVGA  */
    OV2640_VIDEO_FORMAT_CAP(352, 288, VIDEO_PIX_FMT_RGB565),   /* CIF   */
    OV2640_VIDEO_FORMAT_CAP(640, 480, VIDEO_PIX_FMT_RGB565),   /* VGA   */
    OV2640_VIDEO_FORMAT_CAP(800, 600, VIDEO_PIX_FMT_RGB565),   /* SVGA  */
    OV2640_VIDEO_FORMAT_CAP(1024, 768, VIDEO_PIX_FMT_RGB565),  /* XVGA  */
    OV2640_VIDEO_FORMAT_CAP(1280, 1024, VIDEO_PIX_FMT_RGB565), /* SXGA  */
    OV2640_VIDEO_FORMAT_CAP(1600, 1200, VIDEO_PIX_FMT_RGB565), /* UXGA  */
    OV2640_VIDEO_FORMAT_CAP(160, 120, VIDEO_PIX_FMT_JPEG),     /* QQVGA */
    OV2640_VIDEO_FORMAT_CAP(176, 144, VIDEO_PIX_FMT_JPEG),     /* QCIF  */
    OV2640_VIDEO_FORMAT_CAP(240, 160, VIDEO_PIX_FMT_JPEG),     /* HQVGA */
    OV2640_VIDEO_FORMAT_CAP(320, 240, VIDEO_PIX_FMT_JPEG),     /* QVGA  */
    OV2640_VIDEO_FORMAT_CAP(352, 288, VIDEO_PIX_FMT_JPEG),     /* CIF   */
    OV2640_VIDEO_FORMAT_CAP(640, 480, VIDEO_PIX_FMT_JPEG),     /* VGA   */
    OV2640_VIDEO_FORMAT_CAP(800, 600, VIDEO_PIX_FMT_JPEG),     /* SVGA  */
    OV2640_VIDEO_FORMAT_CAP(1024, 768, VIDEO_PIX_FMT_JPEG),    /* XVGA  */
    OV2640_VIDEO_FORMAT_CAP(1280, 1024, VIDEO_PIX_FMT_JPEG),   /* SXGA  */
    OV2640_VIDEO_FORMAT_CAP(1600, 1200, VIDEO_PIX_FMT_JPEG),   /* UXGA  */
    { 0 }
};

static int ov2640_write_reg(const struct i2c_dt_spec *spec, uint8_t reg_addr,
                uint8_t value)
{
    uint8_t tries = 3;

    /**
     * It rarely happens that the camera does not respond with ACK signal.
     * In that case it usually responds on 2nd try but there is a 3rd one
     * just to be sure that the connection error is not caused by driver
     * itself.
     */
    while (tries--) {
        if (!i2c_reg_write_byte_dt(spec, reg_addr, value)) {
            return 0;
        }
        /* If writing failed wait 5ms before next attempt */
        k_msleep(5);
    }
    LOG_ERR("failed to write 0x%x to 0x%x", value, reg_addr);

    return -1;
}

static int ov2640_read_reg(const struct i2c_dt_spec *spec, uint8_t reg_addr)
{
    uint8_t tries = 3;
    uint8_t value;

    /**
     * It rarely happens that the camera does not respond with ACK signal.
     * In that case it usually responds on 2nd try but there is a 3rd one
     * just to be sure that the connection error is not caused by driver
     * itself.
     */
    while (tries--) {
        if (!i2c_reg_read_byte_dt(spec, reg_addr, &value)) {
            return value;
        }
        /* If reading failed wait 5ms before next attempt */
        k_msleep(5);
    }
    LOG_ERR("failed to read 0x%x register", reg_addr);

    return -1;
}

static int ov2640_write_all(const struct device *dev,
                const struct ov2640_reg *regs, uint16_t reg_num)
{
    uint16_t i = 0;
    const struct ov2640_config *cfg = dev->config;

    for (i = 0; i < reg_num; i++) {
        int err;

        err = ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, regs[i].addr, regs[i].value);
        if (err) {
            return err;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

static int ov2640_soft_reset(const struct device *dev)
{
    int ret = 0;
    const struct ov2640_config *cfg = dev->config;

    /* Switch to DSP register bank */
    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, BANK_SEL, BANK_SEL_SENSOR);

    /* Initiate system reset */
    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, COM7, COM7_SRST);

    return ret;
}

static int ov2640_set_level(const struct device *dev, int level,
                int max_level, int cols, const uint8_t regs[][cols])
{
    int ret = 0;
    const struct ov2640_config *cfg = dev->config;

    level += (max_level / 2 + 1);
    if (level < 0 || level > max_level) {
        return -ENOTSUP;
    }

    /* Switch to DSP register bank */
    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, BANK_SEL, BANK_SEL_DSP);

    for (int i = 0; i < (ARRAY_SIZE(regs[0]) / sizeof(regs[0][0])); i++)    {
        ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, regs[0][i], regs[level][i]);
    }

    return ret;
}

static int ov2640_set_brightness(const struct device *dev, int level)
{
    int ret = 0;

    ret = ov2640_set_level(dev, level, NUM_BRIGHTNESS_LEVELS,
            ARRAY_SIZE(brightness_regs[0]), brightness_regs);

    if (ret == -ENOTSUP) {
        LOG_ERR("Brightness level %d not supported", level);
    }

    return ret;
}

static int ov2640_set_saturation(const struct device *dev, int level)
{
    int ret = 0;

    ret = ov2640_set_level(dev, level, NUM_SATURATION_LEVELS,
            ARRAY_SIZE(saturation_regs[0]), saturation_regs);

    if (ret == -ENOTSUP) {
        LOG_ERR("Saturation level %d not supported", level);
    }

    return ret;
}

static int ov2640_set_contrast(const struct device *dev, int level)
{
    int ret = 0;

    ret = ov2640_set_level(dev, level, NUM_CONTRAST_LEVELS,
            ARRAY_SIZE(contrast_regs[0]), contrast_regs);

    if (ret == -ENOTSUP) {
        LOG_ERR("Contrast level %d not supported", level);
    }

    return ret;
}

static int ov2640_set_output_format(const struct device *dev,
                int output_format)
{
    int ret = 0;
    const struct ov2640_config *cfg = dev->config;

    /* Switch to DSP register bank */
    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, BANK_SEL, BANK_SEL_DSP);

    if (output_format == VIDEO_PIX_FMT_JPEG)    {
        /* Enable JPEG compression */
        ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, IMAGE_MODE, IMAGE_MODE_JPEG_EN);
    } else if (output_format == VIDEO_PIX_FMT_RGB565)   {
        /* Disable JPEG compression and set output to RGB565 */
        ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, IMAGE_MODE, IMAGE_MODE_RGB565);
    } else {
        LOG_ERR("Image format not supported");
        return -ENOTSUP;
    }
    k_msleep(30);

    return ret;
}

static int ov2640_set_quality(const struct device *dev, int qs)
{
    int ret = 0;
    const struct ov2640_config *cfg = dev->config;

    /* Switch to DSP register bank */
    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, BANK_SEL, BANK_SEL_DSP);

    /* Write QS register */
    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, QS, qs);

    return ret;
}

static int ov2640_set_colorbar(const struct device *dev, uint8_t enable)
{
    int ret = 0;
    const struct ov2640_config *cfg = dev->config;

    uint8_t reg;

    /* Switch to SENSOR register bank */
    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, BANK_SEL, BANK_SEL_SENSOR);

    /* Update COM7 to enable/disable color bar test pattern */
    reg = ov2640_read_reg(&cfg->i2c, COM7);

    if (enable) {
        reg |= COM7_COLOR_BAR;
    } else {
        reg &= ~COM7_COLOR_BAR;
    }

    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, COM7, reg);

    return ret;
}

static int ov2640_set_white_bal(const struct device *dev, int enable)
{
    int ret = 0;
    const struct ov2640_config *cfg = dev->config;

    uint8_t reg;

    /* Switch to SENSOR register bank */
    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, BANK_SEL, BANK_SEL_SENSOR);

    /* Update CTRL1 to enable/disable automatic white balance*/
    reg = ov2640_read_reg(&cfg->i2c, CTRL1);

    if (enable) {
        reg |= CTRL1_AWB;
    } else {
        reg &= ~CTRL1_AWB;
    }

    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, CTRL1, reg);

    return ret;
}

static int ov2640_set_gain_ctrl(const struct device *dev, int enable)
{
    int ret = 0;
    const struct ov2640_config *cfg = dev->config;

    uint8_t reg;

    /* Switch to SENSOR register bank */
    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, BANK_SEL, BANK_SEL_SENSOR);

    /* Update COM8 to enable/disable automatic gain control */
    reg = ov2640_read_reg(&cfg->i2c, COM8);

    if (enable) {
        reg |= COM8_AGC_EN;
    } else {
        reg &= ~COM8_AGC_EN;
    }

    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, COM8, reg);

    return ret;
}

static int ov2640_set_exposure_ctrl(const struct device *dev, int enable)
{
    int ret = 0;
    const struct ov2640_config *cfg = dev->config;

    uint8_t reg;

    /* Switch to SENSOR register bank */
    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, BANK_SEL, BANK_SEL_SENSOR);

    /* Update COM8  to enable/disable automatic exposure control */
    reg = ov2640_read_reg(&cfg->i2c, COM8);

    if (enable) {
        reg |= COM8_AEC_EN;
    } else {
        reg &= ~COM8_AEC_EN;
    }

    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, COM8, reg);

    return ret;
}

static int ov2640_set_horizontal_mirror(const struct device *dev,
                int enable)
{
    int ret = 0;
    const struct ov2640_config *cfg = dev->config;

    uint8_t reg;

    /* Switch to SENSOR register bank */
    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, BANK_SEL, BANK_SEL_SENSOR);

    /* Update REG04 to enable/disable horizontal mirror */
    reg = ov2640_read_reg(&cfg->i2c, REG04);

    if (enable) {
        reg |= REG04_HFLIP_IMG;
    } else {
        reg &= ~REG04_HFLIP_IMG;
    }

    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, REG04, reg);

    return ret;
}

static int ov2640_set_vertical_flip(const struct device *dev, int enable)
{
    int ret = 0;
    const struct ov2640_config *cfg = dev->config;

    uint8_t reg;

    /* Switch to SENSOR register bank */
    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, BANK_SEL, BANK_SEL_SENSOR);

    /* Update REG04 to enable/disable vertical flip */
    reg = ov2640_read_reg(&cfg->i2c, REG04);

    if (enable) {
        reg |= REG04_VFLIP_IMG;
    } else {
        reg &= ~REG04_VFLIP_IMG;
    }

    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, REG04, reg);

    return ret;
}

static int ov2640_set_resolution(const struct device *dev,
                uint16_t img_width, uint16_t img_height)
{
    int ret = 0;
    const struct ov2640_config *cfg = dev->config;

    uint16_t w = img_width;
    uint16_t h = img_height;

    /* Disable DSP */
    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, BANK_SEL, BANK_SEL_DSP);
    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, R_BYPASS, R_BYPASS_DSP_BYPAS);

    /* Write output width */
    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, ZMOW, (w >> 2) & 0xFF); /* OUTW[7:0] (real/4) */
    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, ZMOH, (h >> 2) & 0xFF); /* OUTH[7:0] (real/4) */
    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, ZMHH, ((h >> 8) & 0x04) |
                            ((w>>10) & 0x03)); /* OUTH[8]/OUTW[9:8] */

    /* Set CLKRC */
    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, BANK_SEL, BANK_SEL_SENSOR);
    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, CLKRC, 0x87);

    /* Write DSP input registers */
    ov2640_write_all(dev, uxga_regs, ARRAY_SIZE(uxga_regs));

    /* Enable DSP */
    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, BANK_SEL, BANK_SEL_DSP);
    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, R_BYPASS, R_BYPASS_DSP_EN);

    k_msleep(30);

    return ret;
}

uint8_t ov2640_check_connection(const struct device *dev)
{
    int ret = 0;
    const struct ov2640_config *cfg = dev->config;

    uint8_t reg_pid_val, reg_ver_val;

    ret |= ov2640_write_reg(&cfg->i2c, BANK_SEL, BANK_SEL_SENSOR);
    reg_pid_val = ov2640_read_reg(&cfg->i2c, REG_PID);
    reg_ver_val = ov2640_read_reg(&cfg->i2c, REG_VER);

    if (REG_PID_VAL != reg_pid_val || REG_VER_VAL != reg_ver_val) {
        LOG_ERR("OV2640 not detected\n");
        return -ENODEV;
    }

    return ret;
}

static int ov2640_set_fmt(const struct device *dev,
            enum video_endpoint_id ep, struct video_format *fmt)
{
    struct ov2640_data *drv_data = dev->data;
    uint16_t width, height;
    int ret = 0;
    int i = 0;

    /* We only support RGB565 and JPEG pixel formats */
    if (fmt->pixelformat != VIDEO_PIX_FMT_RGB565 && fmt->pixelformat != VIDEO_PIX_FMT_JPEG) {
        LOG_ERR("ov2640 camera supports only RGB565 and JPG pixelformats!");
        return -ENOTSUP;
    }

    width = fmt->width;
    height = fmt->height;

    if (!memcmp(&drv_data->fmt, fmt, sizeof(drv_data->fmt))) {
        /* nothing to do */
        return 0;
    }

    drv_data->fmt = *fmt;

    /* Set output format */
    ret |= ov2640_set_output_format(dev, fmt->pixelformat);

    /* Check if camera is capable of handling given format */
    while (fmts[i].pixelformat) {
        if (fmts[i].width_min == width && fmts[i].height_min == height &&
            fmts[i].pixelformat == fmt->pixelformat) {
            /* Set window size */
            ret |= ov2640_set_resolution(dev, fmt->width, fmt->height);
            return ret;
        }
        i++;
    }

    /* Camera is not capable of handling given format */
    LOG_ERR("Image format not supported\n");
    return -ENOTSUP;
}

static int ov2640_get_fmt(const struct device *dev,
            enum video_endpoint_id ep, struct video_format *fmt)
{
    struct ov2640_data *drv_data = dev->data;

    *fmt = drv_data->fmt;

    return 0;
}

static int ov2640_stream_start(const struct device *dev)
{
    return 0;
}

static int ov2640_stream_stop(const struct device *dev)
{
    return 0;
}

static int ov2640_get_caps(const struct device *dev,
               enum video_endpoint_id ep,
               struct video_caps *caps)
{
    caps->format_caps = fmts;
    return 0;
}

static int ov2640_set_ctrl(const struct device *dev,
                unsigned int cid, void *value)
{
    int ret = 0;

    switch (cid) {
    case VIDEO_CID_HFLIP:
        ret |= ov2640_set_horizontal_mirror(dev, (int)value);
        break;
    case VIDEO_CID_VFLIP:
        ret |= ov2640_set_vertical_flip(dev, (int)value);
        break;
    case VIDEO_CID_CAMERA_EXPOSURE:
        ret |= ov2640_set_exposure_ctrl(dev, (int)value);
        break;
    case VIDEO_CID_CAMERA_GAIN:
        ret |= ov2640_set_gain_ctrl(dev, (int)value);
        break;
    case VIDEO_CID_CAMERA_BRIGHTNESS:
        ret |= ov2640_set_brightness(dev, (int)value);
        break;
    case VIDEO_CID_CAMERA_SATURATION:
        ret |= ov2640_set_saturation(dev, (int)value);
        break;
    case VIDEO_CID_CAMERA_WHITE_BAL:
        ret |= ov2640_set_white_bal(dev, (int)value);
        break;
    case VIDEO_CID_CAMERA_CONTRAST:
        ret |= ov2640_set_contrast(dev, (int)value);
        break;
    case VIDEO_CID_CAMERA_COLORBAR:
        ret |= ov2640_set_colorbar(dev, (int)value);
        break;
    case VIDEO_CID_CAMERA_QUALITY:
        ret |= ov2640_set_quality(dev, (int)value);
        break;
    default:
        return -ENOTSUP;
    }

    return ret;
}

static const struct video_driver_api ov2640_driver_api = {
    .set_format = ov2640_set_fmt,
    .get_format = ov2640_get_fmt,
    .get_caps = ov2640_get_caps,
    .stream_start = ov2640_stream_start,
    .stream_stop = ov2640_stream_stop,
    .set_ctrl = ov2640_set_ctrl,
};

static int ov2640_init(const struct device *dev)
{
    struct video_format fmt;
    int ret = 0;

#if DT_INST_NODE_HAS_PROP(0, reset_gpios)
    const struct ov2640_config *cfg = dev->config;

    ret = gpio_pin_configure_dt(&cfg->reset_gpio, GPIO_OUTPUT_ACTIVE);
    if (ret) {
        return ret;
    }

    gpio_pin_set_dt(&cfg->reset_gpio, 0);
    k_sleep(K_MSEC(1));
    gpio_pin_set_dt(&cfg->reset_gpio, 1);
    k_sleep(K_MSEC(1));
#endif

    ret = ov2640_check_connection(dev);

    if (ret) {
        return ret;
    }

    ov2640_soft_reset(dev);
    k_msleep(300);

    ov2640_write_all(dev, default_regs, ARRAY_SIZE(default_regs));

    /* set default/init format SVGA RGB565 */
    fmt.pixelformat = VIDEO_PIX_FMT_RGB565;
    fmt.width = SVGA_HSIZE;
    fmt.height = SVGA_VSIZE;
    fmt.pitch = SVGA_HSIZE * 2;
    ret = ov2640_set_fmt(dev, VIDEO_EP_OUT, &fmt);
    if (ret) {
        LOG_ERR("Unable to configure default format");
        return -EIO;
    }

    ret |= ov2640_set_exposure_ctrl(dev, 1);
    ret |= ov2640_set_white_bal(dev, 1);

    return ret;
}

/* Unique Instance */
static const struct ov2640_config ov2640_cfg_0 = {
    .i2c = I2C_DT_SPEC_INST_GET(0),
#if DT_INST_NODE_HAS_PROP(0, reset_gpios)
    .reset_gpio = GPIO_DT_SPEC_INST_GET(0, reset_gpios),
#endif
};
static struct ov2640_data ov2640_data_0;

static int ov2640_init_0(const struct device *dev)
{
    const struct ov2640_config *cfg = dev->config;

    if (!device_is_ready(cfg->i2c.bus)) {
        LOG_ERR("Bus device is not ready");
        return -ENODEV;
    }

#if DT_INST_NODE_HAS_PROP(0, reset_gpios)
    if (!gpio_is_ready_dt(&cfg->reset_gpio)) {
        LOG_ERR("%s: device %s is not ready", dev->name,
                cfg->reset_gpio.port->name);
        return -ENODEV;
    }
#endif

    uint32_t i2c_cfg = I2C_MODE_CONTROLLER |
                    I2C_SPEED_SET(I2C_SPEED_STANDARD);

    if (i2c_configure(cfg->i2c.bus, i2c_cfg)) {
        LOG_ERR("Failed to configure ov2640 i2c interface.");
    }

    return ov2640_init(dev);
}

DEVICE_DT_INST_DEFINE(0, &ov2640_init_0, NULL,
            &ov2640_data_0, &ov2640_cfg_0,
            POST_KERNEL, CONFIG_VIDEO_INIT_PRIORITY,
            &ov2640_driver_api);
```

I just want a quick runthrough of how to use the driver in an application